# Android Toolbar : shadow on top instead of bottom

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I use the standard Android Toolbar android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html

I want to place this toolbar at the bottom of my screen => I want the shadow at the top and not at the bottom of the toolbar.

How can I do this?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you provide a piece code that you have tried?

Comment: My mistake, I did not see that there was some code to put a shadow at the bottom. There is no method linked to the Toolbar class to add a shadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the following gradient in your drawables folder

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000"
    android:angle="90"
    />
</shape>
```

And then use it in your layout as follows

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <View android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Probably this is what you wanted. :)